# Register-ObjectEvent Event Subscription Uptime

Tags: powershell, listener, powershell-3.0

We have a data dump come from an external entity on a daily basis. Once we receive the file, a Object Event Listener triggers, moves the file into two separate locations (one live, one backup) and then calls a MS SQL stored procedure to import the file into the database.

The process and my script seem to function perfectly fine. The file moves, and the SQL is executed. However, every morning when I check to see if it triggered, nothing triggered. I check for event-subscribers by calling `Get-EventSubscriber` and there are no listeners registered. Once I register the listeners and move the file into the input location, everything runs fine.

I understand that the Event Subscriptions do not persist through reboots, but how long do they stay open? is it possible that something is closing them? or do they time out?

```
$watchFolder = "\\server\c$\path\to\inbound\"
$filter = "*.txt"

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $watchFolder, $filter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $false
    NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileMonitor -Action {
    $filePath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $fileName = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
    Write-Host "Source File: $fileName"
    $success = copyFile($fileName, $filePath) #custom function to copy file to multiple destinations

    if ($success) {
        Write-Host "Starting SQL_JOB_NAME Job"
        Set-Location SQLSERVER:\SQL\server\DEFAULT\Databases\msdb\
        $execute_import = "EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'SQL_JOB_NAME';"
        Invoke-Sqlcmd -SuppressProviderContextWarning -Query $execute_import
    } else {
        Write-Host "Something failed along the way: `r`n"
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you close PowerShell process after `Register-ObjectEvent`?

Comment: Welp, that may very well be the case. Aside from really sketchy methods, do you know of any ways to keep a process like this running in the background? Maybe I'll need to end up switching to a .NET application instead of a powershell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As silly as it seems, I learned here that calling `Register-ObjectEvent` if the PowerShell process is closed, the ObjectEvent is also unregistered.

Because the nature of the project required us to have an always-on file listener, we decided that Powershell was not the correct implementation for us.

Instead we implemented a Windows service using the .NET libraries, which are the same used here in PowerShell.

Thanks to [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) for his prompt answer.